# Angular 2 inputs properties are not binding correctly

Tags: angular

My final goal is to build a component to wrap Google Map. A google map object has lots of options.

In Angular1, I read attributes to build a map object options.

With Angular2, I want to do it differently to use properties binding using `inputs`, so that I can achieve one way or two-way binding.

As a first step, with this plunker, https://plnkr.co/edit/PXg79x?p=preview, I tried to read many properties from html and I have set inputs for multiple options. e.g., a, b, c, d, e, f

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  inputs: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      inputs: {{inputs | json}} <br/>
      a:{{a}}, b:{{b}}, c:{{c}}, d:{{d}}, e:{{e}}, f:{{f}}
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)';
  }
}
```

and I used in html like this.

```
  <my-app [a]="1" [b]="2" [c]="3" [d]="4" [e]="5" [f]="6">
    loading...
  </my-app>
```

I was expecting that I see `a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4..` and so on.

But instead, I see `a:, b:, c:, d:, e:..`

What am I doing wrong here?

---- EDIT ----
Also, I don't expect the answer, but if someone can tell me that I can define these inputs dynamically with or without defining `inputs` or `@Input`, it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may sound dumb, but you cant do this with the root component (my-app).. you need to do this in a child component. Since `my-app` is the entire angular application.

e.g.

`src/my-component.ts` file

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  providers: [],
  inputs: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      inputs: {{inputs | json}} <br/>
      a:{{a}} b:{{b}} c:{{c}} d:{{d}} e:{{e}} f:{{f}}
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)';
  }
}
```

`src/app.ts` file

```
//our root app component
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'
import { MyComponent } from './my-component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <my-component a="1" b="2" c="3" d="4" e="5" f="5">
    </my-component>
  `,
  directives: [ MyComponent ]
})
export class App {

}
```

Also, `[a]="1"` tries to look for a variable called `1` in the class context and evaluate it to get its value.. while `a="1"` gets the value `"1"` as a string.

So, having `[a]="myVariable"` would get whatever value is in `myVariable`, while `a="myVariable"` will pass a string literal with the value "myVariable"

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/DhHgED?p=preview

Makes sense?

Edit:

To my knowledge, you cant define inputs dynamically since angular2 compiler needs to know before hand the component definition.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that we should treat root component differently from child components. I have updated your answer with plunker updated.

Comment: Cool! Glad i could help.